# Dynamically creating variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm trying to create a function that can dynamically create variables for adding sprites into a game. Here is what I have so far:

```
function SpriteSetUp(name,src){
    var Sprites = [];

    var i = Sprites.length;

    if(Sprites[Sprites.indexOf(name)] == name){
      return Sprites[Sprites.indexOf(name)];
    }else{
      Sprites[i] = name;
      Sprites[i].src = src;
      return Sprites[Sprites.indexOf(name)];
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for providing your code. Can you tell us what your problem is, or what you're stuck on exactly?

Comment: My main problem is I have no idea how return the value so I can easily access it. e.g: 

newSprite("name", "image src"); 
getSprite("name");

 Although I'm thinking about just make the and object.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating sprite objects and push them into your sprite array?

```
function SpriteContainer() {
    this.sprites = [];

    this.addSprite= function(name, src) {
        var newSprite = new Sprite(name,src);       
        sprites.push(newSprite);
    }

    function Sprite(name, src) {
        this.name = name;
        this.src = src;
    }
}​
```

Comment: I also believe push is your friend here.